# Imprimir array en función llamada no suelta mismo resultado

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa en c++ que, dado un mazo barajado de cartas, debe encontrar todas los números de 1 a n(siendo este el número de cartas que hay). Y cuando termina de recorrer la lista, debe contar un aplauso.
Sin embargo, no pido ayuda para la lógica de este programa, puesto que al pasar el array de cartas a la función que hace el trabajo, parece que ni siquiera recibe bien los valores (esto demostrado con el print de los elementos del arreglo que hago).

Cabe resaltar que no puedo usar punteros.

Gracias de antemano.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int recorrer(int cartas[], int n);

int main(){
    int casos, numCartas, vectorCartas[100];
    ifstream entrada("..\\cartas.txt");
    if(!entrada){
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }
    entrada>>casos;
    for(int i = 0; i<casos; i++){
        cout<<"==========Caso "<<i+1<<"========="<<endl;
        entrada>>numCartas;
        for(int k = 0; k<numCartas; k++){
            entrada>>vectorCartas[k];
        }
        for(int j=0;j<numCartas;j++){
            cout<<vectorCartas[j]<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"Aplausos: "<<recorrer(vectorCartas, numCartas)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int recorrer(int cartas[], int n){
    int aplausos=0, encontradas=0, buscada=1;
    /*while(encontradas!=n){
        for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                if(cartas[j]==i){
                    encontradas++;
                }
            }
            aplausos++;
        }
    }*/
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        cout<<cartas[j]<<endl;
    }
    return aplausos;
}
```

Comment: Entonces así funciona bien pero cuando mueves el código a la función no? Por cierto, el parámetro `int cartas[]` es un puntero, seguro que no puedes usarlos?

Comment: @Mateo En el main imprime bien los valores del array, pero en la función recorrer no lo hace. En el caso donde hay 3 cartas: 2,1,3. En el main imprime esas 3, pero en recorrer imprime: 1,3,0. No puedo usar punteros puesto que no hemos visto ese tema, y no podemos usar cosas sin haberlas visto. Me refiero a usar * o &.

Comment: @Mateo Parece que el 0 que se pone al final corresponde al return de la función, entonces es como si no leyera el primer valor del arreglo. En 2,1,3. Está imprimiendo solo el 1 y 3. Pero le falta el primer 2.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que interpreto es que la función `recorrer()` recibe como parámetro el array `cartas[]` y los cambios no se están reflejando en el array `original`.

Esta función"recorrer() no está alterando el array cartas[], sino que simplemente está imprimiendo los elementos del array sin modificar el contenido.

Ahora, la función recorre el array de cartas en busca de números del 1 al n. Cuando encuentra un número, incrementa el contador `encontradas` y marca la carta como 0 al encontrar un número consecutivo. Luego, incrementa `aplausos` y finalmente devuelve el total de aplausos.

```
int recorrer(int cartas[], int n) {
    int aplausos = 0, encontradas = 0, buscada = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (cartas[j] == buscada) {
                encontradas++;
                cartas[j] = 0;  //Marcaré la carta encontrada
                break;         //Número encontrado, próximo....
            }
        }

        if (encontradas == 1) {
            aplausos++;
        }

        encontradas = 0;
        buscada++;
    }

    return aplausos;
}
```

***** código completo

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int recorrer(int cartas[], int n);

int main() {
    int casos, numCartas, vectorCartas[100];
    ifstream entrada("..\\cartas.txt");
    if (!entrada) {
        cout << "Não foi possível abrir o arquivo";
        exit(1);
    }
    entrada >> casos;
    for (int i = 0; i < casos; i++) {
        cout << "==========Caso " << i + 1 << "=========" << endl;
        entrada >> numCartas;
        for (int k = 0; k < numCartas; k++) {
            entrada >> vectorCartas[k];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < numCartas; j++) {
            cout << vectorCartas[j] << endl;
        }
        cout << "Aplausos: " << recorrer(vectorCartas, numCartas) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int recorrer(int cartas[], int n) {
    int aplausos = 0, encontradas = 0, buscada = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (cartas[j] == buscada) {
                encontradas++;
                cartas[j] = 0;  //Marcaré la carta encontrada
                break;         //Número encontrado, próximo....
            }
        }

        if (encontradas == 1) {
            aplausos++;
        }

        encontradas = 0;
        buscada++;
    }

    return aplausos;
}
```